# OpenCV color histogram calcHist considering only specific pixels (and not full image)

Tags: c++, opencv, colors, histogram

I want to calculate the color histogram of an image but only taking into account specific pixels (whose 2D coordinates I know).

Is it possible to use calcHist specifying that only these concrete pixels should be taken into consideration (instead of the whole cv::Mat and all the pixels in it)? If not, is it possible to create a new Mat including only those specific pixels at known positions, and how? (Considering that for a histogram the pixel coordinates do not matter, could they be added to a (1 x number_of_specific_pixels)-dim Mat keeping the original type of the Mat?)

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: your proposed solution seems viable, why don't you try it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The third parameter of [clalHist](https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.0/d6/dc7/group__imgproc__hist.html#ga4b2b5fd75503ff9e6844cc4dcdaed35d) is called `Mask`.

So, you create a new single channel 8 bit `cv::Mat` that has the same size of your input image. It should contain `255's` where you want to calculate the histogram and `0's` where you do not. Then, pass it as `Mask`.

Comment: Wow, true, I just assumed that the mask could only be a predefined fixed-shape kernel, that's amazing. Thanks a lot!